# How do i fix the if statement in a SignUp page?

Tags: c#, events, if-statement, authentication

How do I fix the IF statement so when the user tries to sign up using an already existing username. Currently my program will not accept the data entered if the username is already existing, but it still proceeds to the next page (even though the data is not saved in the database).  What I need to know is how to eliminate the problem so when the user does enter a "username" that exists it'll just give the message box for the error and not move to the next page.

Thanks!

```
private void btnSignupNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   if (txtUsername.Text == "")
   {
      errorUsername.SetError(txtUsername, "Enter A Username");
   }

   else if (txtPassword.Text == "")
   {
      errorPassword.SetError(txtPassword, "Enter A Valid Password");
   }

   else
   {
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=etc"))
      {
         con.Open();
         bool exists = false;

         // create a command to check if the username exists
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [User] where UserName = @UserName", con))
         {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUsername.Text);
            exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
         }

         // if exists, show a message error
         if (exists)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Username: " + txtUsername.Text + "  already Exists");
            //errorPassword.SetError(txtUsername, "This username has been using by another user.");
         }    

         else
         {
            // does not exists, so, persist the user
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] values (@Forename, @Surname, @Username, @Password)", con))
            {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Forename", txtForename.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", txtSurname.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUsername.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", txtPassword.Text);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
          }
          con.Close();

          MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Signed Up");
          Form1 signin = new Form1();
          signin.Show();
          this.Close();
       }
   }      
}
```

}

Comment: You parameter names are wrong.  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUsername.Text);` should be `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text);`.  This is true for all of them.

Comment: first problem I see is in this line here ` cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUsername.Text);` should be this ` cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text);` Insert statement needs to have the `@` in front of each param name as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is always going to close the form and launch the login form, regardless of whether the username already existed or not, because the logic to do the login form is executed *after* your test for uniqueness. It should only happen when the test for uniqueness suceeds.

Change your logic to look like this:

```
// if exists, show a message error
if (exists)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username: " + txtUsername.Text + "  already Exists");
           //errorPassword.SetError(txtUsername, "This username has been using by another user.");
}
else
{
    // does not exists, so, persist the user
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] values (@Forename, @Surname, @Username, @Password)", con))
    {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", txtForename.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Signed Up");
    Form1 signin = new Form1();
    signin.Show();
    this.Close();
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: JohnKallen edit that answer to show proper Paremeter `@` names

Comment: Glad to be of help. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Change your Parameters to look like the following as well 
I would also recommend adding some sort of Validation if necessary to the edit boxes in case someone adds improper values to prevent from any `SQL Injectection` personally I would create Property values for the Edit boxes and pass in the Property Value(s). just a suggestion

First problem in your code that stood out to me was the following line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUsername.Text);
```

should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text);

// if exists, show a message error
if (exists)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username: " + txtUsername.Text + "  already Exists");
           //errorPassword.SetError(txtUsername, "This username has been using by another user.");
}
else
{
    // does not exists, so, persist the user
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] values (@Forename, @Surname, @Username, @Password)", con))
    {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", txtForename.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Signed Up");
    Form1 signin = new Form1();
    signin.Show();
    this.Close();
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks DJ KRAZE! and sure ill change the parameter values

Comment: Not a problem glad we could help you out